# Cannot debug any Visual-C Qt application

Tags: windows, qt, debugging, visual-c++

I am working on a Gui Qt application. When deployed with the right dependencies it can be run independently as mingw-release, mingw-debug, msvc-release, and msvc-debug. When debugging under Qt Creator the mingw-debug can be debugged. However debugging the msvc-debug gives a crash. The disassembler shows:

ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart:
0x7ff901ae0d30 sub rsp,48h

This happens with even the most trivial GUI application. I have tried several Qt versions. At present I am using VC 2015 and Qt 5.10. The debugger is part of the Windows SDK kit. I am running Windows 10.

Added on Dec 28:
I can step into the debugger. The crash occurs as soon as the GUI thread is invoked, like window.show();

Comment: Try to separate the reason from many. If you create new Qt example app with MS compiler, will it crash when starting debugger? What if you run that crashing app stand-alone and then attach MS VS debugger to the process and continue? Will the reason of crash appear if you launch the app immediately from MS VS?

Comment: Is version "Qt Creator 4.5.0 CDB Debugger Support" installed?

Comment: Yes it is installed

Comment: I have added some info to the original question. @AlexanderVX: The crash also occurs if debugger is attached later. If I use MS VS to attach to a running (debug) instance nothing happens. There is no crash but also no indication how to set break points (I am not experienced with running MS VS outside Qt.)

Comment: There is some system exception thrown during start-up and that may depend on race condition (I read "added on Dec 28"). That implies no crash for the example app? If so, need to see the source code that may affect the race condition causing a crash.

Comment: @AlexanderVX the crash is on the simple Qt application example (simple editor). When running with WinDbg it stops at ModLoad: 00007ff8`ed4a0000 00007ff8`ed4c6000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SRVCLI.DLL
(3110.32c0): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll - 
ntdll!LdrInitShimEngineDynamic+0x358:
00007ff9`01b471b8 cc              int     3
When I then tell WinDbg to continue application starts normally.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. As long as Qt example is crashing then the problem is with dev. environment setup. To hard to debug from here due to visibility. :) Try to reinstall Qt with Qt Creator? Maybe Windows SDK kit as well needed to be reinstalled.

Comment: I might have found the answer. Qt sets CDB by default to break on thread start and thread exit. After unchecking these options I could debug. So the debugger didnot crash in my case but it stopped at thread start and thread exit.

Comment: Great! Happy New Year!